# Are kernels on the individual machines also in action when multiple users are logged into a common system via a server

Tags: shell, linux-kernel

In a book on Unix, I read the following lines: ***Even though there's only one kernel running on the system, there could be several shells in action - one for each user who is logged in.***
My question is - Since each user is on a different machine, the kernel of each machine is running individually. But since each user is connected via a common server and logged into a common system, it is written in the book that "***only one kernel is running***". Is that the correct explanation of the lines quoted above or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Each physical machine (or VM) runs exactly one kernel. Each user has his/her own login shell and possibly several shells and processes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the users are logged in over e.g. SSH, then the machines running their clients will have some kind of an OS, with some kind of a kernel, and the machine running the SSH server, will also have one. But the server machine itself still has only one kernel handling multiple SSH sessions and shells and whatever other programs the users run.

Also, you don't *have* to have users connecting over a network connection. They might be users on dumb terminals over a serial line, and we don't really think of dumb terminals having an operating system. Or, you could have multiple keyboards and displays directly connected to the same machine. Or, you could have multiple shells open on multiple terminal emulators in the same GUI session, though then they'd likely be used by just one user. In all those cases, you'd have one, and only one kernel involved because there's only one full-blown OS involved.

Comment: Yes, in our lab we use SSH. So that means the students who are on different different machines but are logged into the host machine via SSH, are using their own kernels on their machine and at the same time the kernel of the host machine ?

Comment: @Esha, yes, their applications on the two machines are using services from the kernels on their respective machines.